# Can one realize the real part of every entire function $f$ as $\ln| g|$ with $g$ entire?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, absolute-value

Let $\Re$ denote real part and $|\cdot|$ absolute value.

Does there exist, for every entire $f$, an entire $g$ such that $\Re f = \ln |g|$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the function $g(z)=e^{f(z)}$?